# How to show warning and list of related content

Tags: nodes, entities

I'm working with Drupal and I wanted to show users that the included URL in post has already been submitted when they click preview

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Unique field](https://drupal.org/project/unique_field) module:

> This module performs additional validation when a node is created or
>   updated by a user to require that a node's title, author, language,
>   and CCK fields are unique within a given context.